# Creating table 'Pull Down' Views in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a table that I've rendered using angularjs - Just a list of items with id's on each row.
What I want now is to be able view details of each row in a pull down view maybe a div with a nested table.(This details view will make an async call to the server to pull the required data based on the row id).
I probably can accomplish this using a regular bootstrap modal, but i would like to do it in a pull down view on the same parent page.
All of this is possible with jquery, but I'd like to implement it using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

The following will achieve what you're looking for:

1. Use `ng-click` to bind a click event to the table row
2. Use the `$http` service to talk to the server and retrieve details of the clicked ID
3. Use a bit of jQuery to add the row containing your detail info to the table.The DOM manipulation for tables is much easier in jQuery than Angular.If you really want to use Angular for that then it's up to you to rewrite the example below in Angular or normal javascript, there are a TON of examples on the web showing you how to do this.

Here's a complete example:

**Controller:**

public class AngularController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(int id)
{
    //Write the code to get the specific details for the passed through id
    var user = new {Name="User Name",Surname = "User surname" };
    return Json(user,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

}

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .close {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $(document).on("click", "span.close", function () {

            $(this).parent().parent().empty();

        });
    });

    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {

        var current = "";

        $scope.ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        $scope.RowClick = function (i) {

            $http.get("/Angular/SomeActionMethod/" + i).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                $('#users > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                    var tr = $(this);
                    var isPopup = $(tr).hasClass("popup");

                    if (!isPopup) {

                        var children = $(tr).children();
                        var id = children[0].innerText;


                        if (id == i && current != id) {
                            alert($(tr).html());
                            $("<tr class='popup'><td>" + data.Name + " " + data.Surname + "&nbsp;<span class='close'>X</span></td></tr>").insertAfter(tr);
                            current = id;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <table id="users">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in ids">
                <td ng-click="RowClick(i)">{{i}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output:**
[image]